# Permanently delete a shortened link from bit.ly

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly

I want to delete a shortened link from bit.ly that was created by me.

How can I do that?

Comment: This question never gets old. Apparently they still don't allow users to permanently delete their bitlinks. So now that I have posted personal information as part of my source URL, it stays on the web for all eternity? Nothing is eternal, and neither should bitlinks be. Web was built to be broken, it's full of broken links. I rather break a few links to keep control of my data.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I advise you to look for an alternative service that puts you in control of your data.

Comment: Because I can't answer this question myself, I'll leave a comment here: [you can now delete links that haven't been edited or aren't redirects](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/230903368-How-do-I-delete-a-link-); i.e., you didn't change the back half of the URL. It's a step in the right direction, but I want to delete some old edited links, which I bet is true for most of us here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible at this time.  You can archive a link such that it won't show in your Manage listings, but that won't prevent the link from being used by someone who has the link already.

[Source](http://bit.ly/pages/help#i_1_2)

> **Can I delete a bit.ly link?**
>
> We believe that being a legitimate shortening service means offering permanent URLs. Our users can feel confident that the bit.ly links they create don't unexpectedly disappear or expire.
>
> **How do I remove or archive links from my bit.ly History page?**
>
> You can remove a bit.ly link from your history by opening the Options drop down menu and selecting the Archive link from the choices there (the other choices are Share, Copy, and Edit). Remember that links archived from your public history are still permanently functional and will always redirect to their original destination. Note: for some related bit.ly basics, see: http://bit.ly/Ovnvf

Comment: Do you know of URL shortener that supports deletion?

Comment: As of 24 May 2018, this is still the case. Sadly!

Comment: Sadly, in 2021, this is still the case. Even if the link that has been edited with a new custom link, the old link still stays and cannot be reused again.